# Can qemu-system-x86_64 boot a luks volume?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu

Lets say I have a computer with 2 bootdrives. I install Ubuntu to one and Debian to the other, and I encrypted both during installation. I only specify two different distributions to help distinguish between the drives.

I boot from the drive where I installed Debian, and I log in. Would it be possible to run qemu-system-x86_64 and target /dev/sdb (the drive where I installed Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot access the "full" system this way, Virtualization concept is to install a secondary & third &..... OS inside virtual machines hosted by the OS of the host machine.

So you install debian on the disk, you install the virtualization hypervisor you choose (virtualbox, libvirt, etc....), then you create your virtual disks & virtual machines.

Then you can access them from a virtual network interface & route with ssh or remote desktop ...